# Rails Tutorial Authenticate Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following the Rails Tutorial Modeling Users Chapter: http://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#cha-modeling_users.

My user.rb looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  has_secure_password
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

and my user model spec looks like:

```
describe User, :type => :model do

   before do
     @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                 password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
   end

   subject { @user }

   it { should respond_to(:name) }
   it { should respond_to(:email) }
   it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
   it { should respond_to(:password) }
   it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
   it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

   it { should be_valid }

   ... (other methods are here) 

describe "when password is not present" do
   before do
     @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                   password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
   end
   it { should_not be_valid }
end
describe "return value of authenticate method" do
   before { @user.save }
   let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

   describe "with valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
   end

   describe "with invalid password" do
     let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

     it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
     specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
   end
end
```

Which I'm pretty sure is exactly a duplication what the Rails Tutorial code is, but I'm getting the following failed test errors:

```
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:83 # User when password is not present should not be valid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:108 # User return value of authenticate method with invalid password should be false
```

Comment: Can you add the complete error trace in the question.

Comment: @infinity it also crossed my mind that please check that there isn't already a user with email address: "user@example.com" in the test database. From command line: 1. rails console test  2. user = User.find_by_email("user@example.com") 3. if the previous command finds a user, then you need to delete it: user.destroy   Alternatively, if the user exists in the database you might wanna consider creating the user in the test with new email address each time (some random part in the email address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked this out by looking at the Ruby on Rails Tutorial Book's source code (Rails 4) at GitHub: [spec/models/user_spec.rb](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/spec/models/user_spec.rb). Based on the code there, it looks like your passwords are currently of acceptable type and that's why your test is failing. I mean your passwords are good. foobar is a valid password. Below an empty string is passed to the User model validation.

```
  describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                       password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

The second one I'm not sure, but would it help if you tried the Rails 3 [spec/models/user_spec.rb](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/spec/models/user_spec.rb)related code for the same test:

```
    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
```

It looks slightly different but it's testing the same thing. This is just suggestion, because I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a couple of methods are missing (if you're trying to match the tutorial exactly) Listing 6.25 & 6.28:

describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

Comment: @indescrete, I have those methods in my spec, I just didn't add them to the question because I didn't think they'd effect the failed tests

Comment: You are totally right. I didn't notice the ... in your code above. In the method "when password is not present" you are using foobar, but I believe that you will want those fields to be empty strings. See Listing 6.25:                                                              describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                       password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

Comment: listing 6.25 should give you failing tests, however, according to the tutorial (unless you've already gone past listing 6.25 and fixed the failing tests)